Can you compare two constant pointers in the C preprocessor?
Say my code looks like this:
gpios.h:
#define GPIO_BASE 0x08000100

#define GPIOA ((GpioRegs *) (GPIO_BASE + 0x04))
#define GPIOB ((GpioRegs *) (GPIO_BASE + 0x0C))
#define GPIOC ((GpioRegs *) (GPIO_BASE + 0x14))

switches.h:
#define SWITCH1_PORT GPIOA    // On this particular system, both switches
#define SWITCH2_PORT GPIOA    // are on the same port. This could change in the future

switches.c:
#if SWITCH1_PORT == SWITCH2_PORT
// Code is a lot simpler if both switches are on the same port
#else
// Otherwise do it the hard way
#endif

SWITCH1_PORT and SWITCH2_PORT are both constants at compile time, so comparing them at compile time should be valid, but in practice I get this error message:
gpios.h:772:45: error: operator '*' has no right operand
  772 | #define GPIOA               ((GpioReg *) (GPIO_BASE + 0x04))
      |                                        ^
switches.h:102:33: note: in expansion of macro 'GPIOA'
  102 | #define SWITCH1_PORT GPIOA
      |                      ^~~~~
switches.c:172:5: note: in expansion of macro 'SWITCH1_PORT'
  172 | #if SWITCH1_PORT  == SWITCH2_PORT
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~

I tried casting the pointers to uint32_t, and I tried defining a COMPARE_POINTERS macro, but nothing helped.
Is there a way to do what I want here?

The preprocessor acts on text, not the values of variables, even constants.

AFAIK, you can't do this with #if, but you can probably do this with an inline function and if. With constant terms, the optimizer will select one path at compile time and elide the other.

@Barmar Except when it doesn't, like when using the #if directive.

If you expand the macros, you can see why it doesn't work as expected:
#if ((GpioRegs *) (GPIO_BASE + 0x04)) == ((GpioRegs *) (GPIO_BASE + 0x04))

AFAIK, you can't do type-casts inside of an #if.  You are likely going to have to make a different set of macros that resolve to integers instead of pointers, eg:
gpios.h:
#define GPIO_BASE 0x08000100

#define GPIOA_INT (GPIO_BASE + 0x04)
#define GPIOB_INT (GPIO_BASE + 0x0C)
#define GPIOC_INT (GPIO_BASE + 0x14)

#define GPIOA ((GpioRegs *) GPIOA_INT)
#define GPIOB ((GpioRegs *) GPIOB_INT)
#define GPIOC ((GpioRegs *) GPIOC_INT)

switches.h:
#define SWITCH1_PORT_INT GPIOA_INT
#define SWITCH2_PORT_INT GPIOA_INT

#define SWITCH1_PORT GPIOA
#define SWITCH2_PORT GPIOA    

switches.c:
#if SWITCH1_PORT_INT == SWITCH2_PORT_INT
// Code is a lot simpler if both switches are on the same port
#else
// Otherwise do it the hard way
#endif


"AFAIK, you can't do type-casts inside of an #if" --> Hmm, I thought is was type casts were ignored.  IOWs you can apply a cast, it just won't do anything.

Thanks. Unfortunately, this is part of a larger project and I can't just rewrite those definitions.

@EdwardFalk he doesn't rewrite them he just creates new ones so this solution should still work for you. Also there should be no reason why you cant alter them as long as they are not renamed.

6.6 "Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types" But even when switching the cast to (int) I get a compiler error. Not sure I understand why. I can't find anyhing in the C standard saying that casts aren't allowed, quite the contrary.

@Lundin It's covered in N3220 6.10.2 Conditional inclusion paragraphs 3 and 13. All non-defined identifiers, including those that look like keywords, are replaced with 0 before integer constant expression itself is evaluated. So casts are not disallowed, only impossible to exist in #if directives.

@user694733 That makes perfect sense, thanks.
